# C# equivalent of VB6 character placeholder

Tags: c#, vb6

Is there a C# equivalent to the @ sign used in the VB6 format function?

> **VB6 (@ Character placeholder)**
>   Display a character or a space. If the string has a character in the position where the @ appears in the format string, display it; otherwise, display a space in that position. Placeholders are filled from right to left unless there is an ! character in the format string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean left-justify or right-justify using `string.Format()`.

In c# it is:

```
string s = string.Format("{0,-10}", 42);
// s = "42        "

string s = string.Format("{0,10}", 42);
// s = "        42"
```

Comment: And I was using PadLeft/PadRight all the time... d'oh.